# Avoiding client/server data synchronization gap

Tags: database, asynchronous, synchronization, client-server, message-queue

I have a client/server architecture where the client does the following on connect:

- Open socket to server and request a stream of changes (the "stream").
- Fetch all data from server (the "snapshot").

So the idea here is that the snapshot will get the client all the relevant data at the point of connect, and the stream will keep sending changes - so that the client does not have to do polling and get snapshots over and over again.

The problem with this is that there is a gap in between the snapshot and stream starting that could result in missed data. Example:

1. Client requests snapshot and stream from server.
2. Server fetches snapshot from db.
3. Another client commits a change to db (snapshot is thus outdated). Change is sent out to all streams.
4. Stream for client has been inited.

As you can see above, the client ends up with an outdated snapshot and since the stream init is asynchronous it can miss out on changes to the database (it never sees the change in step 3).

I have a few ideas on how to solve this, but I am not super happy with any of them so far:

1) Init the stream first, and then fetch the snapshot. I am not convinced this one is safe since this assumes that the streaming server (rabbitmq/kafka/pulsar) doesn´t miss out on messages in transit.
2) Have the stream also push the changes made in the last X seconds before the connection time. This is not great because it makes time assumptions and bets on probability.

All input is appreciated!

Comment: What can you do on the server side? Can you for example enumerate the changes and have the snapshot contain the ID of the last change, so that you can see if any change is missing and request that?

Comment: @md2perpe that is actually what I will end up doing. It was not obvious how to do it in a good way (still haven´t tried it) but it seems that updating the updates entities with the stream id of the update message after they have gone through the stream seems to be a fool proof solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. Let someone else handle this for you (e.g. using Google Cloud Firestore).
2. I'm not sure exactly what the messages will contain but if could make it so that the state of the db is just the sum of all transaction message sent in the stream (i.e. if you replay all the messages in chronological order you always end up with the same state) then you could let the server give each message a monotonically increasing id. When the client reconnects it tells the server its max number and the servers sends all messages with a higher id.

Comment: Thanks. 1) Not an option. 2) This solution (replay of log) is for sure another way of doing this. It would require me to replay the whole log which in my case would usually send a lot of worthless data (overwritten later in the log, unless I do some compacting in betwen the stream and client before sending it off) but it is more elegant than the other solutions so far.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start the stream first and then request the snapshot?

1. Start the stream & queue all received records
2. Request a snapshot
3. Process the snapshot
4. Process queued stream entries (and ignore entries older than the snapshot)
5. Process the stream

Do not process anything from the stream (only queue it for processing internally) until the snapshot have been processed.

Each record should have some sort of token which identifies when the record was changed. So if the stream contains a record older than the one in the snapshot, simply do not process it (during the synchronization phase)

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that the Db that the snapshot is generated from is a different cluster. This would still have to make improbable assumptions about the stream server, that messages being commited at the same time that the stream is being started won´t be missed. A solution proposed by a maintainer of apache pulsar is to persist the changes to db after it has gone through to the stream server, and persist the streamId along with the entity. Then you can with the snapshot get the last streamId that you can then use to start the stream from a specified position. Will update question accordingly